# What hashing algorithm can safely be used to hash sets of keywords in-order to generate unique keys for a database table?

Tags: database, hash, sha1, sha256

I have a need to enforce that entries into my database table contain unique sets of keywords or the entry should be denied. Order does not matter, just that each set of keywords need to be unique. For example:

**take this existing sample record in database:**

record
-- content
-- keywords: ['apple', 'pear', 'orange']

A new record with a keyword array ['apple', 'pear', 'orange'] **denied**
A new record with a keyword array ['apple', 'orange', 'pear'] **denied**
A new record with a keyword array ['apple', 'pear', 'orange', 'grape'] **accepted**

As a solution, it was suggested to me that i hash the sets of keywords (lexically ordered), and use that hash as the unique key for the database entry.

Great suggestion, but two problems:
How do i handle case sensitivity in this scenario?
And is it realistic to believe that collisions are close enough to impossible if i decide to use, say for example SHA-1, to hash *large sets of keywords* (up to 30) and use that hash as my unique key for the database entry without requiring a check for a duplicate?

We're using firebase as our backend, and google charges per document read basis, thus, having to check for duplicates before insertion is not an acceptable nor scalable solution, since a query like that would cost us a fortune if we had to check prior to every record insertion should my table include millions of records.

Comment: you can surely use hashing to reduce the amount of bytes the server will need to compare to detect duplicates, but hashes are not unique. there is still a probability (however small, but nonzero) that two different sets of keywords will end up having identical hashes. queries on indexed columns don't cost a fortune.

Comment: How about `['apple','orange', 'pear']` ?

Comment: I should update the question. Order does not matter.

Comment: You asked how you handle case-sensitivity. The answer is "however you want." Should `[apple, pear, orange]` be the same as `[Apple, pear, OrAnGe]`? If so, then just convert everything to lower case before doing comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

> Having to check for duplicates before insertion is not an acceptable nor scalable solution, since a query like that would cost a fortune should my table include millions of records.

Your concerns are misplaced. Databases are great at using indexes to look things up -- millions of records isn't even an especially large number.

Convert the list of keywords into a canonical form (e.g, by alphabetizing the keywords), then join the words with a separator that won't appear in the keywords (like a comma) and use the result as a unique key in your database. You don't need to use a hash.

Comment: Well, i should have been more specific. We're using google's firebase as our backend. And google charges per document read. Hence, having to query the database containing millions of records for a duplicate every time i attempt to insert a new record is too expensive. ill update the question.

Comment: Surely this database has some sort of support for unique indexes?

Comment: then go for the hash. just in the rare case of hash collision, fall back to comparing content. store length of data to reduce the frequency of lookups.